# MongoDB Update Array If Not Found Push It

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do this with one query, it's not the first time I face it but again I forgot how to. I have a collection which can looks like:

```
{
_id:...,
item: [{
        itemId: '12rgd', 
        qty: 5
       },
       {
        itemId: '1t334',
        qty: 6
       }],
user: 'admin'
}
```

I want to update item qty but what if I don't find the `itemId` I just want to add it to the `item` array?

This is how I can find what I need to update:

```
Items.update({user: 'admin' itemId: '12rgd});
```

How then should I proceed with updating the array `qty` value and if not found add it to array?

Comment: How do you want to update `qty`? Increment or set to a specific value?

Comment: @wdberkeley specfic value